# when i use this function this error appear - i work in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 72876032) (tried to allocate 160 bytes) in E:\xampp\htdocs\E-Commerce\functions\functions.php on line 48

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeZMJ.png)

Comment: Your `count_items` function calls itself. Why? What for?

Comment: Maybe you want `echo $count_items` instead?

Comment: why is there an image of code, rather than actual code?

Comment: just i want to echo the function to get a number of product in database

Comment: do I have to ask my question again? post real code. OH never mind.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing this function infinitely.

Change

```
echo total_times();
```

to

```
echo $count_items;
```

It would also probably be a better idea to

```
return $count_items;
```

And when you call this function do it like this

```
$count = total_time();
echo $count;
```

And it would be better to pass the connection `$con` as a parameter to the function like this and remove the `global $con;`

```
$count = total_time($con);
```

It would also be a better idea to run a `SELECT COUNT(*) as tot` rather then a query that generates a result set unnecessarily.